# Getting "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." when installing php 7.4 on Debian 9 with apt-get

Tags: php, debian, apt

I know I'm not the first to be told this by apt-get, but I think my flavor is unique.  Anyhow, my question is, "how do I resolve this error with apt-get?"  But it might go deeper.

```
root@linode (mods-enabled ): apt-get install php7.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.4 but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.4-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.4-cgi but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried aptitude, which seems to just do nothing:

```
root@linode (mods-enabled ): sudo aptitude install php7.4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php7.4{ab} libpcre2-8-0{a} php7.4 php7.4-cli{a} php7.4-json{a} php7.4-opcache{a} php7.4-readline{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,208 kB of archives. After unpacking 10.7 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-readline : Depends: libncurses5 (>= 6) but 5.9+20140913-1+deb8u3 is installed.
                   Depends: libtinfo5 (>= 6) but 5.9+20140913-1+deb8u3 is installed.
 libapache2-mod-php7.4 : Depends: apache2-bin (>= 2.4.16) but 2.4.10-10+deb8u13 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libapache2-mod-php7.4 [Not Installed]              
2)     php7.4 [Not Installed]                             
3)     php7.4-cli [Not Installed]                         
4)     php7.4-readline [Not Installed]                    



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
root@linode (mods-enabled ): echo $?
0
```

It literally just exits there.  I have tried these too:

```
  apt upgrade
  apt update
  apt-get clean
  apt-get update
  apt-get install -f
```

Nothing seems to unlock me from my little jail.  What can I try next?

Comment: I found the answer!  My apt environment was messed up due to an error during install of Debian 9.  I'll come back again if I have this problem again later.  Sorry for the noise.  I will leave this up as a cautionary tale.  :-)

Comment: Glad you solved it! Please add your answer as an actual answer and accept it, so that SO displays it as solved

Comment: This has somehow worked for me:https://askubuntu.com/questions/615166/no-installation-candidate-when-trying-to-install-gcc

Comment: I had the same issue, this somehow worked for me : https://askubuntu.com/questions/615166/no-installation-candidate-when-trying-to-install-gcc

Comment: [Who were you, Rich?  What did you see?!](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png)